# Lag in PDF annotation with pen

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations

I am trying to implement drawing on a PDF with an open source PDF libary in c#.
Unfortunatley the strokes get rendered way to slowly...

This is the problem:

1. I draw a line

[image]

2. Then it gets rendered ...which takes about 0.3s

[image]

3. Finnaly I can draw the next line

[image]

This is really annoying.
I did not write the name of the PDF libary by purpose that I use, because what I would like would be a general solution or suggestion of how to get rid of such lag.

Comment: Well not seeing any code at all makes it hard to suggest which part of it to improve. One way to create slow drawing is to use the MouseMove event without making sure it doesn't waste time by drawing a new segment for every pixel you move/draw. Also: I would try to separate the drawing and the rendering into the pdf.. Your keeping the pdf lib secret makes no sense to me, btw.

Comment: @Taw yes, sorry. Thanks for the answere. I am using PDFsharp